# MySQL: 2 separate queries run very fast, combined query with OR runs very slow

Tags: mysql

```
EXPLAIN 
SELECT inet_ntoa(src) as source, inet_ntoa(dst) as dest,
    firewall.name as fw, proto.proto, service, action.action, 
    sum(count) as hits, max(date) as lastused, rule_uid.rule_uid 
FROM log, action, firewall, proto, rule_uid 
WHERE ( rule_uid.id = log.rule_uid ) 
    AND ( proto.id = log.proto ) 
    AND ( log.action = action.id AND action.action='accept' ) 
    AND ( log.orig = firewall.id) 
    AND ( ( src >= inet_aton('0.0.0.0') 
            AND src <= inet_aton('255.255.255.255') ) )
    AND ( ( xlatedst >= inet_aton('173.82.122.94') 
            AND xlatedst <= inet_aton('173.82.122.94') ) ) 
GROUP BY src, dst 
ORDER BY hits DESC, dst 
LIMIT 100;
```

uses temporary/filesort, 92 lines, and runs in 30ms.

Similarly fast if I modify the query to search for the same IP in the dst column.

But if I combine both queries to search for that IP in the **xlatedst OR the dst** columns:

```
SELECT inet_ntoa(src) as source, inet_ntoa(dst) as dest, 
    firewall.name as fw,  proto.proto, service, action.action, 
    sum(count) as hits, max(date) as lastused, rule_uid.rule_uid 
FROM log, action, firewall, proto, rule_uid 
WHERE( rule_uid.id = log.rule_uid ) 
    AND ( proto.id = log.proto ) 
    AND ( log.action = action.id AND action.action='accept' )
    AND ( log.orig = firewall.id) 
    AND ( ( src >= inet_aton('0.0.0.0') 
            AND src <= inet_aton('255.255.255.255') ) ) 
    AND *( ( xlatedst >= inet_aton('173.82.122.94') 
             AND xlatedst <= inet_aton('173.82.122.94') )
         OR ( dst >= inet_aton('173.82.122.94') 
              AND dst <= inet_aton('173.82.122.94') ) 
         )* 
GROUP BY src, dst 
ORDER BY hits DESC, dst
LIMIT 100;
```

then it examines 2121544 rows and runs for 3 minutes.

Now I could just run both queries and concat the results. But I wonder if there is a simpler way?

There is a seperate index on both "dst" and "xlatedst". Why isnt it used?

Comment: I've edited the SQL to make more readable, just waiting for a peer review before you can see it.

Comment: What's the point of doing a range between with the same IP in `xlatedst` and `dst`? Also can you post your indexes for the table and the explain output for the second query?

Comment: The point is, I need to know if that IP is either in dst, or in xlatedst :-) they dont contain the same IP's and the user can't know in which field the requested IP is. Meanwhile I've changed it to use the BETWEEN operator.

Answer (score 4):

In my experience though, doing anything with an OR condition can have horrible implications when running queries, have you considered running this as two separate queries and then combining the results?

E.g.

```
SELECT * FROM (

    SELECT inet_ntoa(src) as source, inet_ntoa(dst) as dest,
        firewall.name as fw, proto.proto, service, action.action, 
        sum(count) as hits, max(date) as lastused, rule_uid.rule_uid 
    FROM log, action, firewall, proto, rule_uid 
    WHERE ( rule_uid.id = log.rule_uid ) 
            AND ( proto.id = log.proto ) 
        AND ( log.action = action.id AND action.action='accept' ) 
        AND ( log.orig = firewall.id) 
        AND ( ( src >= inet_aton('0.0.0.0') 
                AND src <= inet_aton('255.255.255.255') ) )
        AND ( ( xlatedst >= inet_aton('173.82.122.94') 
                AND xlatedst <= inet_aton('173.82.122.94') ) ) 
    GROUP BY src, dst 
    ORDER BY hits DESC, dst

    UNION ALL

    SELECT inet_ntoa(src) as source, inet_ntoa(dst) as dest,
        firewall.name as fw, proto.proto, service, action.action, 
        sum(count) as hits, max(date) as lastused, rule_uid.rule_uid 
    FROM log, action, firewall, proto, rule_uid 
    WHERE ( rule_uid.id = log.rule_uid ) 
        AND ( proto.id = log.proto ) 
        AND ( log.action = action.id AND action.action='accept' ) 
        AND ( log.orig = firewall.id) 
        AND ( ( src >= inet_aton('0.0.0.0') 
                AND src <= inet_aton('255.255.255.255') ) )
        AND ( ( dst >= inet_aton('173.82.122.94') 
              AND dst <= inet_aton('173.82.122.94') ) ) 
    GROUP BY src, dst 
    ORDER BY hits DESC, dst

) ORDER BY hits DESC, dst
LIMIT 100;
```

That may do the job, or something similar :)

Comment: While the query could stand some more refactoring, your answer is concise and seems very plausible to me. +1 !!!

Comment: It's a sledgehammer approach but it often does the trick.

Comment: Maybe a sledgehammer is just what he needs :-).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why, but after messing around for a couple hours (changing several things in parallel) the queries now all run very fast (<1 sec). This is a current example of what it looks like now: (sorry I'm unfamiliar with the formatting to make it readable) (I didnt change anything in the database, only the query string)

```
SELECT
    inet_ntoa(src) as source,
    inet_ntoa(xlatesrc) as xlate_src,
    inet_ntoa(dst) as dest,
    inet_ntoa(xlatedst) as xlate_dst,
    firewall.name as fw,
    proto.proto, service,
    action.action, sum(count) as hits,
    max(date) as lastused,
    rule_uid.rule_uid
FROM
    log, action, firewall, proto, rule_uid
WHERE
    ( rule_uid.id = log.rule_uid ) AND
        ((src >= inet_aton('1.1.1.1') AND src <= inet_aton('255.255.255.255'))
        OR
        (xlatesrc >= inet_aton('1.1.1.1') AND xlatesrc <= inet_aton('255.255.255.255'))
    ) AND
    (
        (dst >= inet_aton('173.82.122.94') AND dst <= inet_aton('173.82.122.94'))
        OR
        (xlatedst >= inet_aton('173.82.122.94') AND xlatedst <= inet_aton('173.82.122.94'))
    ) AND
    (proto.id = log.proto) AND
    (log.action = action.id AND action.action='accept')  AND
    ( log.orig = firewall.id )
GROUP BY
    fw, proto, service
ORDER BY
    hits DESC, dst
LIMIT
    100
;
```